# A shortcut to create a new guide and place it on mouse click (Photoshop 2019)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, guides

Is there a way to create a shortcut, or to write a script, so that once the shortcut is pressed, a guide appears under the mouse pointer and moves with the mouse until next click. Once the mouse is clicked, a guide is placed.

Comment: Isn't dragging from a ruler just as easy?

Comment: @Scott, the original question is not about what is easier.

Comment: I realize that. Which is why I didn't post an answer but a comment instead. No answer to my question though? `:)`

Comment: sadly script doesn't allow to wait for userinput :( so i'm feared it can't be done

Answer (score 1):

There's no such hotkey and to my knowledge, there's no way of getting mouse coordinates from Photoshop via scripting, so it's not possible. (Might be possible with external automatisation application like AHK on Windows though)