# Photoshop Guides Question

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When someone is trying to make a guide, you drag a line from the ruler (CTRL + R) and drag it to your desired position.

I want to create a guide using an (action, script, shortcut key) so that it appears on my pointer location, is this possible? Using Photoshop 2023

The reason for this is to make things faster and more efficient

Comment: Very similar to [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/121981/84899).